# Splitting an array into two parts

Tags: python, numpy, vector

A row vector is given that may look like any of the following

```
    [10, 10, 10, 11, 10, 9, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    [200, 199, 200, 199, 198, 201, 201, 0, 1, 1]
    [99, 100, 98, 99, 100, 100, 100, 140, 139, 141]
```

The point being that one side is significantly larger than the other. Using python, is there a clean way to find where the split occurs?

Comment: can you please clarify on what basis do you want to split the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Iterate through the list.  Make a running statistical analysis; standard deviation should be plenty, given these examples.  When you find a severe outlier, partition the list there.  All of your splits are well beyond the typical 3-sigma criterion for an outlier.

Does that get you going?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to check if an entry is bigger or smaller than the mean of the array. This code provides a function that finds the index where the split occurs in your examples. It is not statistically robust but will work in the standard cases you mentioned

```
import numpy as np

def cut(arr):
    m = np.mean(np.array(arr))
    arr = arr - m
    arr = arr > 0
    return np.sum(arr)
```

`cut([10, 10, 10, 11, 10, 9, 0, 0, 1, 0])` return `6`, `cut([10, 10, 10, 11, 10, 9, 0, 0, 1, 0])` returns `7` and `cut([99, 100, 98, 99, 100, 100, 100, 140, 139, 141])` returns `3`, which are the indexes of the first or last element of the "group" containing the smallest values.